# FineUploader breaks after Html refresh

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying out FineUploader functionality. I have DIV that contains the upload button and an image element.

When the image is uploaded, I render a new DIV on the server side, and then replace the old DIV, with the new one. The new DIV contains the new image url in the image element and thus the user sees the image refreshed on the page.

The problem is that right after I replace the old DIV with the new one, FineUploader breaks. The upload button no longer opens up the FineUploader dialog. I've verified that this is in fact what's happening, by commenting out the code that replaces the old DIV with the new one, and then simply refreshing the page manually. Now the upload buttons works correctly again, by opening up file upload dialog. So it seems that FineUploader doesn't like the old button replaced with the new button when DIV is replaced, even though html is identical.

Is there a way to "rebind" FineUploader to a new button? How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader embeds a "hidden" `<input type="file">` in the visible upload button (which is apparently a `<div>` in your case). Even if you replaced that container/button with a new one containing another hidden `<input type="file">`, all data and event handlers that Fine Uploader tied to the original file input are now gone, so Fine Uploader doesn't know when a new file is selected, and it can't track that button among other file inputs on the page that it may also be responsible for controlling.

If you'd like to add new buttons, you have two options:

1. Declare these buttons via [the `extraButtons` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#extraButtons) when creating an instance of Fine Uploader. You can show/hide these extra buttons or move them around the page however you like.
2. Create your own file input button, attach a change event listener, and then add whatever files have been selected in that event handler to Fine Uploader using [the `addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles).

In your specific case, instead of replacing an entire set of elements, consider simply using JavaScript to update the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element with the new URL from your server. You can easily get this information in a Fine Uploader [`onComplete` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete), provided your server returns the new URL in the upload response. Or you can simply make an ajax request to your server at any time and use the URL in the response to replace the `src` on your `<img>`.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for your reply. I did as you suggested, and just replaced the div where the image was, not the whole, bigger div, that was encompassing the FineUploader in it. And it works:) It's just that there was another thing updated besides the image div, that's why I was replacing the whole thing from the start, but that's ok, I just replace the two things that changed and now things are working. Thanks for explaining how things works and giving excellent suggestions on how to fix problems in other ways. Very much appreciated!

Comment: p.s. You can mark this as the answer. I don't have enough points to do so:(

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I'm not able to mark my own answer as the accepted answer, but you certainly can as you don't need to have a certain number of points to accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Oh ok, duh, I was clicking the UP arrow.